# PHP throw new exception not working

Tags: php, class, email, exception, throw

I created an E-mail class in PHP but it always returns success even when post data is empty. The exceptions clearly aren't working and I'm  wondering why it's not sending any email as well. Here's the code:

```
<?php

class Contact
{
    private $toEmail = 'example@outlook.com', $subject = 'Personal Site - Contact';
    private $name, $email, $message;

public function __constructor(array $arr)
{
    if(!empty($arr['name']) && !empty($arr['email']) && !empty($arr['msg']))
    {
        $this->name = $this->ValidateName($arr['name']);
        $this->email = $this->ValidateEmail($arr['email']);
        $this->msg = $this->SanitizeMessage($arr['msg']);

        $this->SendMail($this->name, $this->email, $this->msg);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Please fill all the required fields");
    }
}

private function ValidateName($name)
{
    if(ctype_alpha($name))
    {
        return $name;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private function ValidateEmail($email)
{
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        return $email;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

private function SanitizeMessage($msg)
{
    return htmlentities($msg);
}

private function SendMail($name, $email, $msg)
{
    $mailHeader = "From: " . $email . "\r\n"; 
    $mailHeader .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n"; 
    $mailHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

    $messageBody = "Name: " . $name . "";
    $messageBody .= "Email: " . $email . "";
    $messageBody .= "Comment: " . nl2br($msg) . "";

    if(mail($this->toEmail, $this->subject, $messageBody, $mailHeader))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception('Message couldn\'t be sent');
    }
}
}

try
{
    $obj = new Contact($_POST);
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    echo json_encode($ex);
}

echo json_encode('Message was sent succesfully');

?>
```

Comment: LOL... wrong post.  Sorry.

Comment: Why do you have a method called `__constructor`??

Comment: You might want to consider having the `ValidateX` methods throw an exception and catching it in the `__construct` with a try/catch and then throwing. That way all invalid calls result in a catchable exception instead of some returning `null`.

Comment: Also, `Contact` is not a good name for the class, as it could be interpreted as a noun (object stores a record) or a verb (object performs an action). In fact, if it does not store anything but only executes an action and does so in the constructor, it should also be declared [`static`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor is `__construct()`, not `__constructor()`. That function is never called.
Also, avoid doing actions in constructors, setting variables, that's OK, but actually sending mail on creating a new object is unexpected for most developers.

Comment: i actually used my ide autocomplete for that o.O, ill try that thx